# Magento 2.3.5-p1 free shipping configuration issue

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping, tax-calculation, magento2.3.5-p1

I recently upgraded from **2.2.7** to **2.3.5-p1**.
The **free shipping** was set to **29€** but it does not calculate correctly anymore. I bet it's ignoring the taxes.
For example:-

1. my minimum for free shipping it's 29€
2. I have a cart with the total of 34€(including taxes) and all have 23% tax rate, the free shipping does not appear.
3. But if I go to an order of 41€ it already appears, that's why I'm betting on the tax calculation but didn't find anything relative to that.

Any way to check and fix this? I'm not putting this updated version live just because of this.

Thanks :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not answer the question either, didn't find any solution, but as a workaround what I did was using a module for shipping, I created all the needed ones and a free shipping with all the values that I wanted, but I couldn't disable the default free shipping because, at least in the previews versions, it as to be enabled to work with the rules if a rule adds free shipping to the order by some condition, so I increased the minimum amount of the default free shipping to 99999 this way it's enabled but almost impossible to be showed(and if some client spend that much and it shows the default free shipping that's a no problem really with that value xD) unless forced by some rule.
It is not a solution but if someone stumble across this, hope this can at least help as a workaround for now.

Thanks :D